# Ensuring initialization methods complete before member variable is accessed

Tags: java, static, synchronization, locking

Is there a way of ensure that a set of methods operating on a **volatile static** member variable via *one thread* will be done and over with before *other threads* access this member variable? I am trying something like this, but I am not sure if it would work.

```
public class MyClass
{
  private static final Object lock = new Object();
  public static volatile MyObj mo; //assume null will be checked before access

  public static void initialize()
  {
    if (mo == null)
    {
      synchronized(lock)
      {
        mo = new MyObj();
        mo.doInit();
        mo.doMoreInit();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are looking for the `Singleton` pattern and this code does **not** do it anywhere near correctly.

Comment: Do you intend to implement the singleton pattern? Your `mo` field can be replaced as it is now, so I am not sure what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delay the assignment of `mo` until *after* all the methods are called (i.e. use a local variable and then assign `mo` as the *last* step).

Note, you are essentially implementing double checked locking (although using volatile makes it work "correctly").  you need to check `mo` for null again *within* the synchronized block.

also, there are some other (somewhat better) patterns for this like using the class initialization pattern for managing the synchronization.  Pretty much every pattern imaginable is detailed here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: Could you expand on the other patterns in your answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the singleton pattern, using the double-checked locking idiom:

```
private static volatile MyObj obj = null;

public static MyObj getObj() {
    if (obj == null) {
        synchronized (MyClass.class) {
            if (obj == null) {
                obj = new MyObj();
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Note that the field is private, and accessed vie a `getObj()` method (and only through this method). If a field is public, any thread can access it whenever it wants to: you can't synchronize the access to a field without encapsulating its accesses behind methods.

There are easier ways to have this guarantee, but if you want lazy initialization, all of them, AFAIK, will require calling a method.

Comment: What about _delayed assignment_ as jtahlborn suggested? I would like a solution that doesn't require changing how the member variable is accessed.

Comment: public fields should generally be avoided. public static non-final fields should be avoided even more. And when multi-threading come into play, they're an even bigger no-no. Do the right thing, and avoid them.

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean, but the code base I'm working on is not my own. A lot of lousy developers worked on it, it's old and rusty and a big mess. Changing the field to private and using method access is going to be costly.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a getter and have some flags which it checks to ensure that whatever methods are executed. The getter can either wait for the execution to finish to launch the required methods itself.

Comment: Isn't there a synchronization-based solution that will simply lock the variable from being accessed until initialization is complete? Something that doesn't require changing how the member variable is accessed (imagine hundreds of places in code).

Comment: @ADTC: Not that I know of.